# GRUB boot into Windows 7 breaks GRUB and makes system unbootable

Tags: grub2, 12.04, windows-7, mbr

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 (daily-live iso from 21.04.12) alongside Windows 7 on an HP EliteBook laptop.

The installation went fine, except that it installed grub onto my usb disk (/dev/sdb) instead of the hard disk (/dev/sda). I was able to boot into the Ubuntu installation by using the usb disk which had grub installed on it. I then installed grub manually onto the hard disk (/dev/sda) by running "grub-install /dev/sda".

After I do that, I can book into either Ubuntu or Windows 7 from the Grub menu. However, after booting into Windows 7, grub doesn't load on the next boot. The computer simply reboots again and again, without giving any error. The screen simply goes black and reboots. There are two entries for Windows 7 in grub: for /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda3. These are in reality a single Windows installation which uses both partitions. Booting into either of them produces the same effect.

If I boot into the Ubuntu partition using the usb disk, I have found that I can restore grub to working order by using the boot-repair application. Then if I boot into Windows again, grub breaks again.

Full details of the log file which boot-repair produces, showing the partition details, are here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/940155/

Any ideas?

Comment: From log : Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda3 [Found two windows partition] better solution is re-install windows7 and then recover ubuntu grub.

Comment: I don't have any way to re-install windows 7.

Comment: can you please explain why?

Comment: Because I don't have any Windows 7 installation disks. In any event, I don't think the fact that there are two Windows partitions is the problem.

Comment: After load windows7 it changes boot loader(MBR). What does this means? Windows is changing your MBR, fix windows anyway. Not a ubuntu issue.

Comment: I have the exact same problem and I think I have a correlation with the use of zenworks. Twice already The bootloader broke and after a short flash of GRUB loading... the computer resets. Both times right after zenworks was fixed because it complained some services were not running, it recovered and I installed some programs. I suspect the programs needed some work early in the boot cycle and windows decided to break the bootloader. I now have to fix it again. I have a backup of the mbr (first 512 byte), would that be enough to restore grub?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This not really an "*answer*". The content would be a better match to a comment, but is too long-winded to fit in one. Apologies :-(

Some questions just to make sure I am reading your question correctly. (Please update/edit your question if you any further info to add.)

- You say "*I installed grub manually onto the hard disk (/dev/sda).*"
  So you have already booted into the 12.04 installed on partition `sda5` and successfully run
  `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`?
- You say that "*... after booting into Windows 7, grub doesn't load on
  the next boot. The computer simply reboots again and again.*"
  Does it make any difference which of the two entries for Windows in your GRUB menu you use to boot into Windows?
  There is one for `/dev/sda1` (label "OSDisk") and another for `/dev/sda3` (label "BDEDrive").
- Is there ***any*** error or status information at all displayed prior to or during this infinite boot loop? Can you tell if it is Linux/GRUB or Windows that is looping?

I am wondering if there is some conflict between your two Windows boot configurations. Only one of them would seem to be needed. (Probably the one on the first partition, OSBoot?)

Perhaps you might learn something by installing a Windows boot utility such as [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) and making sure your Windows boot settings are correct?

---

Another alternative might be to bring up the Windows 7 [Advanced startup options](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Advanced-startup-options-including-safe-mode) boot menu by pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> **immediately** after starting a Windows boot from the GRUB menu. If the option to `Repair your computer` is available in the advanced options boot menu, you could run `Startup repair` to check for and (maybe) correct problems in your Windows boot setup.

*Note:* You have to be quick pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> or Windows will just boot as usual.

---

I'm not sure exactly what is going wrong, but could there be some corruption in either your Windows or Linux file systems?

The excerpt below is from your boot-repair log from lines 616 to 641. The repeated failures of `getcwd()` (get current working directory) and the GRUB warning about ZISD (ZENworks Image Safe Data ?) might mean something. Do you use ZENworks?

```
REPAIROK:
Copied Win boot files from sda3 to sda1
Reinstall the GRUB of sda5 into all MBRs of disks with OS or not-USB
Reinstall the GRUB of sda5 into the MBR of sda
dpkg --configure -a sda5
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
grub-install (GRUB) 1.99-21ubuntu3
grub-setup: warn: Sector 5 is already in use by ZISD; avoiding it.  This software may cause boot or other problems in future.  Please ask its authors not to store data in the boot track.
SETUPOUTPUT: SETUPEXIT:0
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
/usr/sbin/grub-setup: warn: Sector 5 is already in use by ZISD; avoiding it.  This software may cause boot or other problems in future.  Please ask its authors not to store data in the boot track.
INSTALLOUTPUT: Installation finished. No error reported.
INSTALLEXIT:0
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
Generating grub.cfg ...
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic-pae
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Yes, Zenworks is installed on the machine. I believe that my office uses it to update software and install new programs used for my office.

I have used the application which you suggested - EasyBCD - to install a new boot record with a Windows boot manager, and to add entries on it for Windows 7 and for Ubuntu. I can now happily boot into both operating systems, so that's fantastic.

Comment: Glad EasyBCD worked for you! (I'm the author)

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall GRUB again

# grub-install /dev/sda

You should have a grub.conf in /boot/grub, if not try

# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

Comment: If I am reading the information in [paste.ubuntu.com/940155](http://paste.ubuntu.com/940155/) correctly, line 55 implies there **is** a `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` in `sda5`.

Answer (score 0):

Some Windows programs use and overwrite parts of the boot sector. These parts are unused by the Windows boot loader but GRUB needs them. Whenever you boot into Windows parts of  GRUB will then be overwritten.

From my "Ubuntu view" here I can't really tell which program might be the culprit but you may find it in one of the following groups:

> - Boot sector viruses (rare nowadays - but who knows)
> - Antivirus software (look e.g. for Boot-Sector "protection")
> - Other "safety"- or "protection"-suites
> - Automated backup solutions
> - Custom drivers/software from your PC manufacturer
> - Copyright-"protection" from software

**Of course this list is incomplete but it may help you to get an idea where to look.**

To test if something overwrites your MBR you may want to compare your boot loader from when GRUB is loading and after you booted Windows. Just copy and safe the Master Boot Record to a file by this command (assuming you boot from /sda):

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/<path>/boot_loader bs=446 count=1
```

Answer (score 0):

When booted into windows you could use easy bcd to recover the windows MBR but being also able to get a menu to choose between windows and ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem after installing xampp on the windows partition of a dual boot Windows 7/Debian system. Grub then stopped functioning and looped back on itself. Difficult to say what the cause is, since there was an automatic windows update during the same period. Super Grub Disk from supergrubdisk.org was able to recover the windows os, but Debian has disappeared. Still trying to recover Debian.