# Reboot from windows causes infinte reboot cycle - from Ubuntu it's fine?

Tags: grub2, windows, windows-xp, reboot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GRUB boot into Windows 7 breaks GRUB and makes system unbootable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124055/grub-boot-into-windows-7-breaks-grub-and-makes-system-unbootable)

I installed Ubuntu on a laptop with custom Windows XP installed. It reboots fine and launches Ubuntu and everything works.

When I reboot from windows though, the grub menu is gone. The computer starts going in to this weird reboot cycle, where I see the BIOS screen then it goes black. After that, I see the BIOS screen again and this repeats.

The only solution is to reinstall Ubuntu. Then I get the grub menu back and I can go into windows but the same thing happens on reboot from Windows.